# FCGI returns 500 error on No Auth/doesn't authenticate on Basic Auth

Tags: c++, authentication, openam, fastcgi, apache2.2

I am having a bit of a problem with FCGI in C++.

Originally, it was an application that would use Basic Auth in order to validate any incoming requests (with some validation methods, etc).

We are now trying to incorporate SSO into the installation, using OpenAM as an IDP.

We have been able to communicate with OpenAM without much difficulty (in terms of sending a redirect message from the SP to the IDP using [Lasso](http://lasso.entrouvert.org/)), but the real difficulty is when the IDP redirects back.

If Basic Auth is turned on in Apache, the authorization headers won't be passed, and the user won't be validated.

If Basic Auth is turned off, FCGI throws an exception stating:

```
[Mon Mar 09 14:33:33 2015] [error] [client 10.12...] FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/fcgi" aborted: protocol error: invalid version: 10 != FCGI_VERSION(1), referer: "http://...:8080/OpenAM-12.0.0/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp?ReqID=...&index=null&acsURL=&spEntityID=https%3A%2F%2F...%2F&binding="
[Mon Mar 09 14:33:33 2015] [error] [client 10.12...] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/fcgi", referer: "http://.../OpenAM-12.0.0/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp?ReqID=...&index=null&acsURL=&spEntityID=https%3A%2F%2F...%2F&binding="
```

My fcgi.conf looks like this:

```
FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:8082 -idle-timeout 3600 -appConnTimeout 3600
    <Location "/fcgi">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Protected"
        AuthGroupFile None
        FastCgiAuthorizerAuthoritative Off
        FastCgiAuthenticatorAuthoritative Off
        FastCgiAuthenticator /var/www/fcgi
        Require valid_user
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to replay the user's password for the protected application. I don't believe there is a way to force the browser to send certain request headers along with requests (other than making Ajax calls).

From your description it looks like you are using Apache, which unfortunately doesn't support Basic Auth (with password replay) at the moment, only IIS agents implement that at the moment.

I think OpenIG could resolve your use-case as that supports password replay (similarly to the IIS agents), but that will mean then that you'll need to have OpenIG to act as a reverse proxy in front of your FCGI application.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I have found a workaround code wise in order to get what I want, but I will look into OpenIG and see if it's plausible.